# How can i configure Bjyprofiler for Doctrine2 in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Help , plz how can i configure Bjyprofiler for doctrine2 ? 
all the configurations i found is about pdo , i' m working with zend framework 2 and doctrine2.

```
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => function ($sm) use ($dbParams) {
                $adapter = new BjyProfiler\Db\Adapter\ProfilingAdapter(array(
                    'driver'    => 'pdo',
                    'dsn'       => 'mysql:dbname='.$dbParams['database'].';host='.$dbParams['hostname'],
                    'database'  => $dbParams['database'],
                    'username'  => $dbParams['username'],
                    'password'  => $dbParams['password'],
                    'hostname'  => $dbParams['hostname'],
                ));

                if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
                    $logger = new Zend\Log\Logger();
                    // write queries profiling info to stdout in CLI mode
                    $writer = new Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('php://output');
                    $logger->addWriter($writer, Zend\Log\Logger::DEBUG);
                    $adapter->setProfiler(new BjyProfiler\Db\Profiler\LoggingProfiler($logger));
                } else {
                    $adapter->setProfiler(new BjyProfiler\Db\Profiler\Profiler());
                }
                if (isset($dbParams['options']) && is_array($dbParams['options'])) {
                    $options = $dbParams['options'];
                } else {
                    $options = array();
                }
                $adapter->injectProfilingStatementPrototype($options);
                return $adapter;
            },
        ),
    ),
);
```

Any help is appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: Answer will be: you can't. It is built for Zend\Db

Comment: https://github.com/manuakasam/SamUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had worked for me. now i am getting Zend/db Queries in developer tool.so Well you can add some code in your composer.json file like

```
    "bjyoungblood/bjy-profiler": "dev-master",
```

then update composer!

```
    php composer.phar update
```

then let your application know about your changes.change your application.config

```
    return array(
'modules' => array(
    'ZendDeveloperTools',
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule',
    'Application',
    'BjyProfiler'
),
'module_listener_options' => array(
    'module_paths' => array(
        './module',
        './vendor'
    ),
    'config_glob_paths' => array(
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php'
    )
)
);
```

hope it will also work for you.
thank you.

Comment: thanks for your answer , i can see the queries in the zendDevelopperTool bar , but i still got a problem , when i have queries called using ajax i can't see them ... do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: you are welcome.if you want queries in your developer tool then be in mind that you are not redirecting or reloading your web pages.so please check once your ajax success function.i am exploring..